# In CakePHP 1.3, is there a callback for use after a `saveAll()`?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Using CakePHP 1.3, is there is a callback that is fired *after* a `saveAll()` on a model, or a way to implement such a behavior?

Maybe `afterSave()` already does this?

Specifically, I would like to run a couple particular methods, but only **after related items have been saved**, and only if the parent item is a newly saved instance.

Something like the `$created` argument, passed to `afterSave()`, obviously seems perfect, but I'm at least 90% certain that `afterSave()` is called on a model after the initial save -- which I understand has to happen **before** the related models are saved (so that they have something to put in the FK field).

**What do you suggest for obtaining this behavior?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a callback for `Model::saveAll()` built into CakePHP, but I believe you can override that method on the model to create your own, like so:

```
// In your Model class...
function saveAll($data = null, $options = array()) {
    parent::saveAll($data, $options); 
    $this->afterSaveAll(); // Your new custom callback. 
}

function afterSaveAll() { 
    // Callback code. 
}
```

I am not currently sure about how to produce a `$created` variable behavior similar to what `Model::afterSave()` has, however.

Comment: One note on this: ensure that your overriding `saveAll()` method returns a boolean. Otherwise, you'll probably get an error reported. For example, using the code above, `return $this->AfterSaveAll()`. I bumped into this while working on a similar problem where I had omitted the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

afterSave() just like save() ...

its called for each model, saveall is just a foreach with save() so the afterSave will be called in each model that the final save() is called in

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
if($this->Recipe->saveAll($this->data)) {
    //Do some stuff and checking for new insert.
    $this->Recipe.doSomeStuff();
    $this->redirect('/recipes');
}
```

Perhaps you can tell that it's a created item because you won't be passing an id. I don't know because you haven't posted any code.