# What callback to use in CakePHP to catch all changes to model?

Tags: cakephp, callback

I want to add a new functionality to my application: executing a action every time a specific column is changed inside of a specific modal. This column is changed in many places in the application via several methods (save(), saveAll(), updateAll(), saveField()).

My first approach was to use the beforeSave/afterSave callbacks to handle this for every change on Modal level. However, I noticed that these callbacks aren't being done with updateAll() and saveField().

Is there a easy way to track **all** changes made to a specific column for a specific modal, regardless of the method being used in modal?

Comment: If you need to ensure that you always catch changes to a column, then I'd recommend using a trigger in the database.

Comment: Why not use afterSave and use it to see if a record was updated instead of created?

Comment: @mcgowan.b I don't think afterSave is called if you update the model via updateAll() or saveField(), is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own callback and use it with save all, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857073/in-cakephp-1-3-is-there-a-callback-for-use-after-a-saveall)